# Re-rewarded a bronze badge several days later?

Tags: bug, badges, achievements-dialog

I got the [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) tag badge several days ago, but today I got this again (overlap previous one):

[image]
[image]

Why would I get this badge again? Is this kind of bug?